# How to vectorize inner loops with omp simd

Tags: fortran, openmp, nested-loops, simd

I have 3 nested loops like this:

```
      !$omp parallel do schedule(runtime) private(s1)
      DO  k = 0, z
         !$omp simd collapse( 2 ) reduction( +: s1 )
         DO  i = 0, x
            DO  j =  0, z
               s1 = s1 + array(k,j,i)
            ENDDO
         ENDDO
         sums_l(k) = s1
      ENDDO
```

But the intel compiler complains with "warning #13379: loop was not vectorized with "simd""
Why is that? How would I do that instead?

//EDIT3: This is code, that produces the error. It is reduced to be the minimum that still causes the error. If you remove literally anything, it vectorizes.

```
SUBROUTINE simdTest

  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER ::  i, j, k, sr, tn,nzb,nzt,nxl,nxr,nys,nyn
  REAL    ::  s1, s2, s3, s4
  REAL, DIMENSION(:,:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: u,v,pt,rmask,sums_l
  REAL, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: usws,vsws,shf

  !$omp parallel do schedule(runtime) private(s1,s2,s3)
  DO  k = nzb, nzt+1
    !$omp simd collapse( 2 ) reduction( +: s1, s2, s3 )
    DO  i = nxl, nxr
       DO  j =  nys, nyn
          s1 = s1 + u(k,j,i)  * rmask(j,i,sr)
          s2 = s2 + v(k,j,i)  * rmask(j,i,sr)
          s3 = s3 + pt(k,j,i) * rmask(j,i,sr)
       ENDDO
    ENDDO
    sums_l(k,1,tn) = s1
    sums_l(k,2,tn) = s2
    sums_l(k,4,tn) = s3
  ENDDO

  !$omp parallel do reduction( +: s1, s2, s3, s4) schedule(runtime)
  DO  i = nxl, nxr
   DO  j =  nys, nyn
      s1 = s1 + usws(j,i) * rmask(j,i,sr)
      s2 = s2 + vsws(j,i) * rmask(j,i,sr)
      s3 = s3 + shf(j,i)  * rmask(j,i,sr)
      s4 = s4 + 0.0
   ENDDO
  ENDDO
  sums_l(nzb,12,tn) = s1
  sums_l(nzb,14,tn) = s2
  sums_l(nzb,16,tn) = s3

END SUBROUTINE
```

Comment: When I correct your code (target => end parallel) it doesn't print this warning. We need more details.

Comment: The access stride of the array in the inner loops is not unity. Fortran uses column-major array storage and hence `array(k,j,i)` and `array(k,j+1,i)` could be very far apart in memory. This is not vectorisable on CPUs without gathered vector loads (i.e. without AVX2) and highly inefficient in many cases even if supported. Therefore the vectoriser might decide that the cost is higher than if the loop is implemented serially.

Comment: Ok, I tried that on Ivy Bridge. I noticed the stride also though.

Comment: The result is: `simd.f90(10): (col. 10) remark: OpenMP SIMD LOOP WAS VECTORIZED` even for a assumed shaped dummy argument.

Comment: Intel's compiler is pretty smart. It could rearrange loops and perform other tricks in order to get the code to SIMD-ise. In that case the loop over `k` can be made innermost and vectorised. Not sure that this is the expected effect of the `simd` construct though. Did you examine the assembly code?

Comment: Alright, thanks for the hints, you are right with that one. However actual code is a bit more complex. See edit please

Comment: The same situation. Why not post the ACTUAL code, not "more like an actual code"?

Comment: Done, just did not want to make it more complicated than it is

Comment: Are you joking? Did you at least try if it produces the problem before posting?

Comment: `ifort -openmp simd.f90 -warn -O3 -c -vec-report=1 -xSSE` ==> `simd.f90(11): (col. 7) remark: OpenMP SIMD LOOP WAS VECTORIZED`

Comment: Strange. Yes I tried and it DID produce the error mentioned. I'll investigate further.
Does it matter, that the array are marked "allocatable"?

Comment: Is USE_DEVICE true or false? Try both and tell us if both produce that or only one of them. Try to come up awith a small self contained and fully compilable example that produces it, not these snippets.

Comment: I just updated the question. The behavior was hard to reproduce with sample code, so I cut down the original code to the bare minimum that still produces the error. It is far away from being valid, so just imagine the variables are global and set before entry to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no more place for this in the comments:

I get this when I compile it at an Ivy Bridge CPU. The loop on line 15 is not profitable to be vectorized on the CPU, but notice it IS VECTORIZED for the Intel MIC architecture. The loop 16 is vectorized on the CPU also with the target directives removed.

The reason for the vectorization problem is in the first remark "subscript too complex".

```
ifort -openmp simd.f90 -warn -O3 -c -vec-report=3 -xHOST -fpp 
ifort: command line remark #10382: option '-xHOST' setting '-xCORE-AVX-I'
simd.f90(17): (col. 33) remark: loop was not vectorized: subscript too complex
simd.f90(15): (col. 5) warning #13379: loop was not vectorized with "simd"
simd.f90(16): (col. 8) remark: LOOP WAS VECTORIZED
simd.f90(13): (col. 3) remark: loop was not vectorized: not inner loop
simd.f90(13): (col. 3) remark: loop was not vectorized: not inner loop
simd.f90(31): (col. 4) remark: LOOP WAS VECTORIZED
simd.f90(30): (col. 3) remark: loop was not vectorized: not inner loop
simd.f90(29): (col. 7) remark: loop was not vectorized: not inner loop
simd.f90(29): (col. 7) remark: BLOCK WAS VECTORIZED
ifort: warning #10362: Environment configuration problem encountered.  Please check for proper MPSS installation and environment setup.
simd.f90(15): (col. 5) remark: *MIC* OpenMP SIMD LOOP WAS VECTORIZED
simd.f90(13): (col. 3) remark: *MIC* loop was not vectorized: not inner loop
simd.f90(13): (col. 3) remark: *MIC* loop was not vectorized: not inner loop
simd.f90(31): (col. 4) remark: *MIC* LOOP WAS VECTORIZED
simd.f90(31): (col. 4) remark: *MIC* PEEL LOOP WAS VECTORIZED
simd.f90(31): (col. 4) remark: *MIC* REMAINDER LOOP WAS VECTORIZED
simd.f90(30): (col. 3) remark: *MIC* loop was not vectorized: not inner loop
simd.f90(29): (col. 7) remark: *MIC* loop was not vectorized: not inner loop
```

Comment: try to remove the s4 =... line and recompile. Loop WILL get vectorized.
So it seems the compiler is wrong here.

Comment: I cannot confirm this. But if I delete the complete block starting at line 28 than it is indeed vectorized. For explanation you will probably have to contact Intel. Preferably through the official channels - the support forum or the Premier support site.